# MATLAB - constructing a random matrix with specific determinant from its submatrices

Tags: matrices, matlab

What Matlab code could be used to generate a random matrix whose $2 \times 2$ submatrices obtained from diagonal and anti-diagonal entries give a determinant of either $+1$ or $ -1$? The needed random matrix is an $n\times n$ but we should consider when constructing such matrix that its $2 \times 2$ submatrices obtained from diagonal and anti-diagonal entries give a determinant of either $+1$ or $ -1$.
Please see the picture below to understand an example of such a matrix.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't your problem boil down to generating random $2\times 2$ matrices with determinant $\pm 1$? You can then just generate random rotation matrices or reflection matrices. Then build your big matrix from that.

Comment: No. I am not generating $2\times 2$ but $n\times n$ whose determinant of its $2\times 2$ submatrices give +1 or -1

Comment: Right, and like I said, you can generate the $2\times 2$ matrices first, and construct your bigger matrix afterwards. If the entries don't need to be integers, then the $2\times 2$ matrices can be random rotation or reflection matrices, which have determinant $\pm 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it.

Let $k$ be the number of diagonal "submatrices" ($k=4$ in your example). It means that the dimensions of your big matrix are $2k \times 2k$ or  $(2k+1) \times (2k+1)$.

- First select a range of variation for your entries, say $[-r,r]$.
- Then generate an exhaustive list $L$ of all possible $2 \times 2$ matrices $M$ with entries in $[-r,r]$ and $\det(M)=\pm 1$. Let $\ell$ be the length of list $L$.
- Then generate $k$ times ($k$ has been defined at the beginning) a random integer number $p \in [1,\ell]$, allowing to select in list $L$ (with possible repetition(s)), $k$ matrices $M$ that remain to be "installed" in your big matrix.

**Remarks :**

1. Matrix list $L$ could be implemented in Matlab by considering a 3-dimensional array, but it would be awkward. It is better to build this list by concatenating them in this way

$$L=[L,M]$$

(with initialization "void list" $L=[ \ ]$) ending up in a $2 \times (2 \ell)$ array to which you will get access by steps of 2 units.

2. Obtaining all $2 \times 2$ matrices with determinant $\pm 1$ can be done by brute force (testing/eliminating) is $r$ is moderate.

These two options are taken in the following Matlab program :

```
   clear all;close all;hold on
   k=4;n=2*k+1;
   r=5;
   ri=@()(floor((2*r+1)*rand-r)); % rand int in [-r,r]
   L=[];
   for s=-r:r
      for t=-r:r
         for u=-r:r
            if (abs(s)>0) && (abs(t)>0) && (abs(u)>0)
               v=(1+t*u)/s;
               if (floor(v)==v) && (abs(v)<(r+1)) && (abs(v)>0);
                L=[L,[s,u;t,v]];end;
               v=(-1+t*u)/s;
               if floor(v)==v && abs(v)<(r+1) && (abs(v)>0);
                L=[L,[s,u;t,v]];end;
            end;
         end;
      end;
   end;
   nm=size(L,2)/2;% number of 2x2 matrices with det = 1 or -1
   % sanity check :
   %D=[];
   %for k=1:2:2*nm
   %  D=[D,det(L(:,k:k+1))];
   %end;
   %hist(D)
   %Initialization
   for p=1:n
      for q=1:n
         M(p,q)=ri();
      end;
   end;
   rng('shuffle');
   for i=1:4;
      r=ceil(nm*rand()+1);
      E=L(:,(2*r-1):(2*r));
      M(i,i)=E(1,1);
      M(i,n+1-i)=E(1,2);
      M(n+1-i,i)=E(2,1);
      M(n+1-i,n+1-i)=E(2,2);
   end;
   M
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your explanation. The explanation is the steps but I need a Matlab code for it. I will appreciate if you can provide that

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.  But can you help me add to the code such that I can specify the range of elements in the matrix? For example, I want numbers between -20 and 20 to fill the matrix entries. Please note that zero should not be part of the entries of the matrix as it would nullify the purpose of creating the code.

Comment: This condition of non-zero entries wasn't in the initial contract :) Let us go. If you want a range of integer uniform random values in $[-20,20]$ excluding $0$, replace line 3 by : `r=20` and line 4 by `ri=@()(sign(rand-0.5)*ceil(r*rand));`. This is for the **initial filling of the big matrix** (done by the 5 instructions following the comment " initialization" : nothing to be changed there). But do you mean that *as well* the little $2 \times 2$ matrices shouldn't have any of their entries equal to zero ?

Comment: I would be interested by knowing the motivation for the contruction of such a matrix (I am puzzled by the "would nullify the prurpose of creating the code" in your last comment...").

Comment: I am sorry for the retraction. It was an error, my apology. The $2\times 2$ submatrices will not also include zero

Comment: I have modified directly the code inside the triple loop "for... for ... for" in order that all little matrices have non-zero entries in [-r,r].